# How to grab the string between the first and last occurrence of a hyphen

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to make a program that, if given string with two dashes in it, returns the text between the first two dashes. If it does not have at least two dashes, it will return that it does not exist. Ex. I have a string

```
String s = "I AM -VERY- HUNGRY"
```

And I want my program to return VERY, which is between the two dashes. Here is my code so far

```
public static String middleText(String sentence)
   {
   int count = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
   {
     if (sentence.charAt(i) == '-')
     {
        count++;
     }
   } 
   if (count >= 2)
   {
     return sentence.substring(sentence.indexOf("-") + 1);
   }
   else
   {
     return "DOES NOT EXIST";
   }
}
```

However, this code does not produce my desired output. If I put the string `I AM -VERY- HUNGRY` into this code, it would return `VERY- HUNGRY`. How can I make it so it grabs the text only until the second dash?

Comment: Keep track of at which index the character is -. Then, take a substring between those numbers...

Comment: `sentence.indexOf("-")` returns the position of the first "-" and `substring` with only one argument gives you the string starting from that position until the end.

Comment: Hint: your method is supposed to return a **String** when things go fine. So returning a String **error** message is really a bad idea! Code using that method would have to check if the returned string is DOES NOT EXIST to figure what is going on. Bad style!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following line:

```
return sentence.substring(sentence.indexOf("-")+1, sentence.lastIndexOf("-"));
```

---

Alternatively use the Regular Expression. See the link for the concrete Regex for this case at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cxlHxk/1).

```
-(\w+)-
```

It matches the following:

- `\w+` means any letter at least one time `+`.
- `()` is capturing group
- `-(\w+)-` captures one or more letters between `-` characters

Combine `Pattern` and `Matcher` to achieve the result.

```
public static String middleText(String sentence) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-(\w)-");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sentence);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return matcher.group(1);
    } else {
        return "DOES NOT EXIST";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to call `find()`? Otherwise it'll only work if string starts and ends with dashes.

Comment: Yes, I mean `find()`. I am sorry and thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Pattern and Matcher (java.util.regex) for this

```
String s = "I AM -VERY- HUNGRY";
Pattern patter = Pattern.compile("-(.*)-");
Matcher matcher = patter.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // VERY
} else {
    System.out.println("no match");
}
```

Comment: If you used `find()`, you wouldn't need the `.*` at beginning and end. It's also more intuitive, since you truly are trying to *find* the text between dashes.

Answer (score 2):

Just use method split of String. [See API here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)). Use String "-" as delimiter, and if your resulting array has length 3 or more then your second member of Array is your result:

```
public String myMatchFinder(String arg) {
    String result = null;
    String res[] = arg.split("-", 3);
    if(res.length == 3) {
      result = res[1];
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException("No matches found");
    }
    return result;
}
```

The "else" block works if no pattern is found. So in this case the exception is thrown as an indicator of no-match, rather then returning a String which could be confused for an actual result. (Say your arg String is **"Hello -no matches found- bye"**. In this case String **"no matches found"** will be your actual result). So with Exception being thrown you can catch it in your invoking code and handle it as an error any way you'd like.

Comment: This is just a simplified example for a newbie. So it will be clear. I certainly would not write this as a real code. I also (almost) never have multiple returns in the same method, but again this is quick and dirty demo.So technically you are correct, but you are just picking at details while the principle solution is correct and is visually demonstrated

Comment: OK, this is better, I agree

Comment: Just one thing left --- there is a typo in that message. And you should *explain* what that else block is doing.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use `indexOf` to get the index of the first hyphen, and `lastIndexOf` to get the index of the last one.  So perhaps something like this:

```
int firstIndex = sentence.indexOf("-");
int lastIndex = sentence.lastIndexOf("-");
return sentence.substring(firstIndex+1, lastIndex);
```

(Note: this code has not been tested, and does not include the kind of error checking that you mentioned.)

Answer (score 1):

And the one line solution...

```
return Optional.of(sentence)
    .map(Pattern.compile("(?<=-).*?(?=-)")::matcher)
    .filter(Matcher::find)
    .map(Matcher::group)
    .orElse("DOES NOT EXIST");
```

Answer (score 1):

**If the string format is consistent - there are always two hyphens with a value inside it** - you may simply use `.replaceFirst` with `^[^-]*-(.*)-[^-]*$` regex pattern and the `$1` placeholder in the replacement pattern:

```
String s = "I AM -VERY- HUNGRY"
String result = s.replaceFirst("(?s)^[^-]*-(.*)-[^-]*$", "$1");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QpAhxU/1) and the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/uUXzgb).

**Details**

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL modifier
- `^` - start of string
- `[^-]*` - 0+ chars other than `-`
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(.*)` - Group 1 (referred to with `$1` from the replacement pattern) - any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[^-]*` - 0+ chars other than `-`
- `$` - end of string.

If there can be any types of hyphens, use `\\p{Pd}` instead of `-` in the code.